# How to get response data back to main class while using asynchronous in Okhttp android Library?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, anonymous, okhttp

I am not able to figure out proper way of doing this. First lets look at the code:

```
//This method Fetch raw json Data
public void fetchJsonData(String url){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request req = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(req);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
             jSonData = response.body().string();

        }
    });
}
```

This method is in a normal class which is not an activity and what I want to do is I want this method to return `jSondata`, simply changing return type from `void` to `String` is not working because, that is in anonymous class as well happening in other thread, I need to assign this `jSonData` variable in other method which will be called from a fragment. 
So, Let me know if there is anyway I can pass variable from here to other method in the same main class.

Comment: If this method is in the same class as the other method that needs the data, then you would just return the String that you are setting in `onResponse` from this method and pass it into the next. So you would just call `theOtherMethod(fetchJsonData(url));`. Another option would be to define a global variable called `String jsonResponse` in the class, and just assign it in your `fetchJsonData` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create method failed and success in your activity. Nice way to do it is create an interface and let activity implement that interface.
To methods be:

```
activity.failed(/*pass failure reasons*/);
```

and

```
activity.success(String data);
```

now change your method to:

```
 public void fetchJsonData(Activity activity,String url){
    final WeakReference<Activity> activityWeakReference = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request req = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(req);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            Activity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.failed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            jSonData = response.body().string();
            Activity activity = activityWeakReference.get();
            if (activity != null) {
                activity.success(jSonData);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I created an interface with two methods failed and success and implemented in my fragment. I am passing getActivity() to  this method from my fragment class and but in this method ... activity.failed() and activity.success(jSonData) are not recognizable. I don't know much about WeakReference still I did as you said.

Comment: so instead of activity pass your fragment here, and change above code accordingly

Comment: ya sorry, I passed "this" instead of getActivity() .. now its working . Thanks. I never knew about WeakReference.

Comment: weakreference is to protect from possible memory leak, i.e if data returned if activity or fragment stops or paused

Comment: By the way I had to create interface object  to access those methods, was not directly accessible using activity or fragment object.

Answer (score 2):

create you own Callback interface.

like this:

```
public abstract class MyCallback implements Callback {
private final Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            onFailureInMainThread(request, e);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResponse(final Response response) throws IOException {
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                onResponseInMainThread(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public abstract void onFailureInMainThread(Request request, IOException e);

public abstract void onResponseInMainThread(Response response) throws IOException;
```

}

then, you can override the two abstract methods.